# How to remove key functionality in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I apologize in advance--I'm brand new to Linux.

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04. I have a keyboard that includes a keypad on the right side. Since I write a lot of notes in BoostNote and I haven't transitioned to Vim yet, I still use the Home and End keys (7 and 9 respectively) on the keypad very often to move within my notes. Because of that, the Number Lock is rarely on.

Unfortunately, the 0 key, when Number Lock is off, toggles Insert. I have no interest in Insert really ever. I'd like to remove that specific functionality, while maintaining the functionality of the number 0 when Number Lock is on.

Is there a way to do this? I've found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/325272/1103141) but, to be honest, I simply don't understand enough of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this using [xkeycaps](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/xkeycaps.1.html).

Alternatively, this is working for me in Fedora 32 (using Xorg rather than Wayland)...

First, copy the keyboard layout to a file in your home directory:

```
xmodmap -pke > ~/.xmodmap
```

You probably want to make a backup of the file, in case your changes make things worse! Next, open the line in your favourite text editor and look for this line:

```
KP_Insert KP_0 KP_Insert KP_0
```

You want to remove `KP_Insert`, so change it as follows:

```
KP_0 KP_0
```

Save the file and import the edited keymap file:

```
xmodmap ~/.xmodmap
```

You can now test if the Ins key prints a zero when numlock is disabled.

Credit: https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?286110-remap-specific-keyboard-keys